Repairing Shower Floor
I have limited experience with shower repairs. Recently, I've noticed that the grout/sealant between the tiles on my shower floor has begun to peel off, and I can see water seeping between the tiles. I would like to understand the necessary steps to address this issue so I can research each step further. Should I remove all the existing sealant, reapply grout, and then reseal? Or is resealing alone sufficient?
Thank you for the help.



If it's built properly, the waterproofing is below the tiles. So you're just regrouting - it's not a sealant.

Still, if the grout is failing, there may be some movement.  OP, do you have grout, or caulk, at the edges of the shower floor?

That loose piece of grout looks way too big for the tile joints. Did they perhaps use sanded grout in an application that should have been unsanded, according to the joint size?

How old is it?  Do you have any gaps filled with flexible or silicon grout?

I just recently moved into the house, i believe it is around 2 years old but don’t have more info than that. There is no caulk, it’s all grout.  I don’t know type of grout it is.
